# How to count households from each postcode in the database

Tags: sql

I made an er diagram for a business and based on which I need to run a query for counting household from each postcode.

```
SELECT CU.POSTCODE, Count(CU.CUSTOMER_ID) AS HOUSEHOLDS_PER_POSTCODE
FROM CUSTOMER AS CU
  INNER JOIN HOUSEHOLD AS HHD ON CU.CUSTOMER_ID = HHD.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY CU.POSTCODE;
```

Is this a good way?

Comment: Does that query run? (Which dbms?)

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, generally that is a good way to do it but (as @jarlh mentioned) it should be either

```
SELECT CU.LOCATION, Count(CU.CUSTOMER_ID) AS HOUSEHOLDS_PER_POSTCODE
FROM CUSTOMER AS CU
  INNER JOIN HOUSEHOLD AS HHD ON CU.CUSTOMER_ID = HHD.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY CU.LOCATION;
```

or

```
SELECT CU.POSTCODE, Count(CU.CUSTOMER_ID) AS HOUSEHOLDS_PER_POSTCODE
FROM CUSTOMER AS CU
  INNER JOIN HOUSEHOLD AS HHD ON CU.CUSTOMER_ID = HHD.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY CU.POSTCODE;
```